# HTML5 Native drag and drop on image as opposed to border?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have implemented drag and drop functionality on a set of images. the problem i am having is that it only works when i drag from the picture border not the picture itself??

I have tried various things but it doesnt seem to work. If i drop a picture not on the right place this also changes to a cropped box too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var source;
function dragStarted(evt){
//start drag
source=evt.target;
//set data
evt.dataTransfer.setData("image/jpeg", evt.target.innerHTML);
//specify allowed transfer
evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
}



function draggingOver(evt){
//drag over
evt.preventDefault();
//specify operation
evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
}

function dropped(evt){
//drop
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
//update text in dragged item
source.innerHTML = evt.target.innerHTML;
//update text in drop target
 evt.target.innerHTML = evt.dataTransfer.getData("image/jpeg");

}
</script>


<ul class="photos columns-3">

<li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)" ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6001.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

<li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)" ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6013.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

<li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)" ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6081.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

<li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)" ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6268.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

<li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)" ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6345.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

<li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)" ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6378.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

<li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)" ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6397.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

<li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)" ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6413.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

    <li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" ondragover="draggingOver(event)"     ondrop="dropped(event)"><img src="images/dsc_6417.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></li>

   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when you put a mouse pointer on image, it is considering the image event and you have done the code for li tag

You can try below code with some changes :

```
var source,imgsrc;
dragStarted = function (evt){
    //start drag
    source=evt.target;
    if(evt.target.tagName == "IMG" ) {
        source=evt.target.parentNode;
        imgsrc=source;
    }

    //set data
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("image/jpeg", source.innerHTML);
    //specify allowed transfer
    evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
}



draggingOver = function (evt){
    //drag over
    evt.preventDefault();
    //specify operation
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
}

dropped = function (evt){
    //drop
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    imgsrc=evt.target;
    if(evt.target.tagName == 'IMG' ) {
        imgsrc=evt.target.parentNode;
    }
    //update text in dragged item
    source.innerHTML = imgsrc.innerHTML;
    //update text in drop target
     imgsrc.innerHTML = evt.dataTransfer.getData("image/jpeg");

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this still only worked when dragging from the border of the image not the image itself

Comment: Can you please tell me the browser in which you are testing? Please check the link : http://jsfiddle.net/T8aPH/

Comment: Thanks, was trying for chrome!